# Unable to to Download .mp3 audio file from server using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to download .mp3 files for each of the words in a dictionary. I have 479831 words taken from the `/usr/share/dict/words` file of a unix machine. For words that don't have audio pronunciation the response is a 404 page, and for correct words it is a .mp3 file with a response code of 200. Some of the files I can download but no proper steam. No audio in those files I tried to download using the below code, but I am getting 2 different errors at two different times.

First Error:

```
 events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    Error: socket hang up
        at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1092:19)
        at TLSSocket.g (events.js:286:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
     PS E:\Development\Node\webscraping>
```

Second Error: sometimes Javascript heap out of memory.

```
var http=require('https');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        var dir='./AudioPronunciationOfWords'
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir))
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        fs.readFile('./wordsList.txt','utf8',function(error,content){
            var listOfWords=content.split('\n');
            var subList=listOfWords.slice(0,1000)       
            var baseUrl='https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/';   
            subList.forEach(function(word){         
                var url=baseUrl;    
                url+=word+'.mp3';       
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var req=http.get(url, function(res) {
                        var status=res.statusCode;
                        console.log(status)
                        if (status===200) {
                            var filename=word+'.mp3';
                            var file = fs.createWriteStream(dir +'/'+ filename);
                            res.on('data', function(data) {
                                    file.write(data);
                            })
                            .on('end', function() {
                                    file.end();              
                                })
                            .on('error',function(err){
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                        }
                        else
                            return;                 
                    });
                    req.end();
                },10000)

    app.listen('8081')
    console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
    exports = module.exports = app;
```

Where I am going wrong? Shall I do it like that? Some of the words I can download using this script but not correctly.

Comment: Is this your entire source file? It seems to be missing some closing braces/parens

Comment: ya but origin code is fine and working

Comment: Well, the problem may be that you're trying to download 1000 files at once. Also, what is the 10-second `setTimeout` for?